# NE602 local oscillator

Tags: oscillator, crystal

I'm making experiments with simple [SA602](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/SA602A.pdf) (formerly NE602) chip to educate myself build radio circuits. I started with local oscillator circuit. I used a 10 Mhz crystal. It oscillates at that frequency. But it is not stable at its khz digits. I assumed it should have been 1000000 Hz.

Is this oscillation normal or should it be a fixed value?

Comment: 1000000 Hz = 1MHz not 10MHz

Comment: Do you have a datasheet for the crystal?

Comment: This sort of confusion is exactly why we use engineering units.  Use whatever units multiplier it takes so that there are 1 to 3 digits left of the point.  Stuff like 1000000 Hz is annoying to look at and leads to error too easily.  If you want to make a point that your frequency is good to 7 decimal places, then write 1.000000 MHz.

Comment: And a schematic of exactly what circuit you built with the SA602?

Comment: When you say it's not stable in the kHz digits... Have you got a frequency counter or something that you measured it with?

Comment: What voltage do you see across the crystal? What is the supply voltage to the chip? Either too much drive or too little can cause stability problems.

Comment: Sorry for notation and writing problems, I was simply measuring it with my self built frequency counter on msp430 processor with Hz unit. You can find the datasheet on [link](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/SA602A.pdf)
And I'm using the reference circuits from this 
[document](http://www.schematicsforfree.com/archive/file/Radios%20&%20RF%20Circuitry/Misc/Using%20the%20NE602%20RF%20Chip.pdf)
I connect pin1 to ground with 10k.Pin2 & pin5 to ground with 4.7nF.Pin4 is output and pin6-7 is configured for crystal.The main problem is don't I need an exact frequency,not a variying one.

Comment: I'm using exact 6 Volts. But maybe I can add a parallel 1M Ohm to crystal.